# Select2 is not working inside the document.ready function

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, jquery-select2

> Hi i'm new in select2. im face a problem in select bcz its not working inside the document.ready function. but working well ouside the document.ready function.

**HTML**

```
<td>
  <select class="form-control select_group product" data-row-id="row_1" id="name_1" name="name[]" style="width:100%;" onchange="getProductData(1)">
     <option value=""></option>
       <?php foreach ($products as $k => $v): ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $v['id'] ?>"><?php echo $v['name'] ?></option>
       <?php endforeach ?>
  </select>
</td>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".select_group").select2();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".select_group").select2();
});
```

```css
.select2-container {
  width: 300px!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control select_group product">
  <option value="one">Option One</option>
  <option value="two">Option Two</option>
  <option value="three">Option Three</option>
</select>
```

It's hard to debug when we don't have much info. Can you please what error you get? It's working fine on my side.

Comment: its not showing any error. if i write the select2 function outside the document.ready function its working well but if i include it inside the document ready function then its not working. and not showing any error

Comment: i believe, given answer is working properly either way. what do you exactly want, working codes, or not working codes??

Comment: actually its not working in document.ready function. i want to use it in document.ready function because im working in dynamic fileds so i need include the code in document,ready function to can use for every select field. but its not working in document.ready function.

Comment: without document.ready function its working but only for the first row but for dunaimc rows i have to include in document.ready function and then its not woking even for the first row select field